# Why is this MySQL INTERSECTION with wrong syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql, intersect

I have two tables, *a* and *b*:

```
+-------------+--------+-----------+
| ID_do_aluno | Nome   | Sobrenome |
+-------------+--------+-----------+
|   154676754 | John   | Brown     |
|   232565690 | George | Yellow    |
|   345896580 | Anne   | Green     |
|   459986789 | Ted    | Purple    |
+-------------+--------+-----------+
```

```
+-------------+--------+-----------+
| ID_do_aluno | Nome   | Sobrenome |
+-------------+--------+-----------+
|   154676754 | John   | Brown     |
|   232565690 | George | Yellow    |
|   342889999 | Rich   | White     |
+-------------+--------+-----------+
```

Im trying to get their intersection. I tried

```
(select * a)INTERSECT(select * from b);
```

and many other variations, but couldnt get it right.
What I need is

```
+-------------+--------+-----------+
| ID_do_aluno | Nome   | Sobrenome |
+-------------+--------+-----------+
|   154676754 | John   | Brown     |
|   232565690 | George | Yellow    |
+-------------+--------+-----------+
```

Thanks in advance, sorry for the begginer's difficulty to locate this well-discussed subject in foruns & documentation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `intersect` in MySQL.  Instead, use `exists` or `in`:

```
select ID_do_aluno, Nome, Sobrenome
from a
where (a.ID_do_aluno, a.Nome, a.Sobrenome) in (select b.ID_do_aluno, b.Nome, b.Sobrenome from b)
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to simulate `INTERSECT` which is not supported by MySql, is by comparing each column of `a` to its respective column of `b` with the null safe equal operator [`<=>`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to), so that `null` values will be considered equal.
Also, `INTERSECT`, in databases that support it, returns distinct rows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.ID_do_aluno, a.Nome, a.Sobrenome
FROM a
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM b
  WHERE b.ID_do_aluno <=> a.ID_do_aluno AND b.Nome <=> a.Nome AND b.Sobrenome <=> a.Sobrenome
)
```

Comment: Wow... didn't know that MySQL implemented `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` as `<=>`. +1 just for that.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't do `INTERSECT` , sadly.